# Types of Models Suitable for Problem with Categorical Time Series Labels

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, categorical-data

I have a situation with a standard input but have to output a set of categorical time series labels. I have had a look at the literature, and there is much to say when we have the reverse situation, i.e. variable length inputs, for example padding. But was wondering what to do with variable length outputs. Is this a situation for  a one to many RNN? Or are there other options?

Comment: You can keep the input length constant ( by zero padding ). Train a sequence-to-sequence RNN model on these inputs so that we can predict sequences of varying lengths. For instance, a seq2seq model can translate a given sentence ( which is padded to a fixed length ) to some other language ( which has a variable length ).

Comment: I just wanted to add that the input is not a sequence. The input is a fixed input feature matrix. So I am having trouble training a seq2seq model. Any suggestions?